# Factoring Real and Complex polynomials.

Tags: polynomials, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

Factor:

a) $x^2 + 1 \in \mathbb{R}[x]$

b) $z^3 - i \in \mathbb{C}[x]$

Well I solved for $x^2$ and got $-i$ and $i$, but they aren't from Real. And I couldn't solve for Complex (part b).

Comment: I am shocked that somebody used $\complement$ (`\complement`) to denote the complex numbers. If they use Fraktur for the reals, they should at least also use $\mathfrak{C}$.

Comment: You should have seen the factorization of $a^3-b^3$ by now, I think. Notice that $i=(-i)^3$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, it seems to me that OP is very new to this game, and I think we should cut him some slack.

Comment: @Lubin It wasn't the OP. If you look at the revisions, he posted an image. Whoever wrote the exercise committed the deed. (I wouldn't have complained about a newbie student doing that.)

Comment: @DanielFischer, thanks for the information. I don’t ordinarily look at revisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that part $(a)$ is trying to say that there are no real roots to that equation.

For the second part, if
\begin{equation}
z^{3} - i = 0
\end{equation}
Then, writing
\begin{equation}
i=\exp\left({\frac{i \pi}{2}}\right)
\end{equation}
means that one root is
\begin{equation}
z=\exp \left({\frac{i \pi}{6}}\right)
\end{equation}

Can you find the other two?

EDIT: All roots to this are of the form;
\begin{equation}
z_{n} = \exp ({i \pi/6 + 2ni\pi/6)}
\end{equation}
Where I have given you the root corresponding to $n=0$. The other two are found by inserting $n=1, 2$ into the roots above. By the way, this way of finding the roots to a complex polynomial is a consequence of De Moivre's Theroem.

Comment: i can hardly read can u enlarge the equation.

Comment: Real roots not real solutions.

Comment: @SherlockHomies: The equations appear of normal size (similar to text size and formulas in other posts) on my laptop.

Comment: it somehow appeared very small. But now it is fixed :). And no i can't see the other two solutions.

Comment: btw is this the only way, how you factorize this expression?

Answer (score 2):

For b) note that $(-i)$ is a root. Then $z^3-i = (z+i)(z^2-zi-1)$. The rest is to find the $2$ roots of $z^2-zi-1 = 0$.

Comment: This is the approach I would have used.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:
a) You cannot factorise deeper. Why?
b) $z^3=i$ and you can find 3 roots of $i$.

Comment: There is no word "factorize" in English. "You cannot factor further" would do nicely here.

Comment: @hardmath [Yes, the spelling is "factorise".](https://www.google.de/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=14VbVOWNOYqcOtjRgNgK&gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=factorise+polynomials&nirf=factoring+polynomials)

Comment: @hardmath, the geezer says that there is a word “factorize” in (American) English, but it has fallen into desuetude.

Comment: @Lubin: Then I shall follow suit!